# LVDS oscillator's complementary output does not swing

Tags: lvds

I am using a SIT9121 27 MHz LVDS oscillator. The MPN is [SIT9121AI-2B2-33E27.000000](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/sitime/SIT9121AI-2B2-33E27-000000/10788457)

The circuit design is shown below.

The 100 Ω resistor is right at the oscillator's output (about 2 mm distance track). It has a balun formed using lumped components. The balun transformer converts the LVDS differential output to single ended 50 Ω. After the balun is a PI attenuator formed of three resistors to attenuate the signal to the required levels.

I have simulated the transfer function of the balun.

When I measured the LVDS signal outputs at pins 4 & 5 of the oscillator, I observed the OUT- pin producing the required LVDS output at 27 MHz, Vos = 1.2V and Vod = 500 mV:

Its complementary LVDS output (pin 5) has a DC = 1.2 V with no swing:

The trace after the balun shows around 540 mV swing around 0 V DC:

Why doesn't the LVDS differential output at OUT+ (pin 5) swing around 1.2 V, while its complementary output oscillates at 27 MHz correctly?

Comment: You can't model an LVDS driver with a floating AC source. You need to model it like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling#/media/File:Basic_LVDS_circuit_operation.png

Comment: Given the use of an attenuator, could you not just terminate one side,, and AC couple and rebias the other?

Comment: You say the oscillator is 27MHz. You show the simulation having gain at 1.5MHz. What explains this discrepancy?

Comment: Simulation is for the the transfer function of the balun circuit only. I wasn't trying to simulate an LVDS driver on this occasion, only trying to see the insertion loss of the balun

Answer (score 1):

LVDS drivers use current sources on the high-side. Driving a Balun with current sources doesn't seem like the right approach. The Balum expects true differential signals.

Simulating the LVDS was more difficult than expected. I am sure that there is a better way to do this. The high-side is straightforward. For the low-side, the ideal diode creates a switch to ground.

At high frequencies, C1 and C2 create a low impedance to ground, so I would expect the Out+ signal to be severely attenuated.

Edit for Justme's comments: Your measurements have a 1.2 V offset which is per the LVDS spec. The simplified model that I grabbed from Wikipedia doesn't include an offset. The AC data still applies for either case.

So basically the answer is: live with what you made; or re-think your entire approach.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feBaPV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without Balun, showing that the LVDS works properly:

[image]

With the Balun, but without the Pi attenuator:

[image]

Comment: The measurements have 1.2V offset, because LVDS is supposed to have 1.2V common mode voltage offset.

Comment: @Justme - Thx, it has been 10 years since I worked with LVDS, I forgot that detail. Apparently, the Wikipedia simplified diagram that I grabbed doesn't include the 1.2V offset.